# What is the logic behind dictionary word search and auto suggestion in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, search

I want to develope an app that is similar to dictionary in MAC. what is the logic to show the words related to the letters typed in textfield and if the word does not exists how can i suggest the words dynamically depending on the letters typed?

Answer (score 0):

You can only suggest those words if you've got a database of words already. The logic is that you request all words that start with what user has typed in from your database and show results in a table view.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, Assume i have an database of few words. now the user miss spells some word and how can i autocorrect and show suggested words i mean the nearest words in tableview. for example if user types korect it should be autocorrected to correct if the word exist in database or if user types dlea i should suggest del, flea,ilea,lea,plea etc as it is in MAC's inbuilt Dictionary

Comment: how can i implement did you mean algorithm similar to apple dictinary?

Answer (score 0):

Look up "radix tree" for some ideas on how to do fast word completion.

Comment: Thanks Danieal, radix tree shows the words starting from the letters typed by user right?. I need to show alternate words if the typed word doesn't exist. how can i do that?

Comment: There are basically three ways: 1) Insert multiple misspellings into your database.  If you're clever you can arrange so that the words still concatenate into a single search phrase, without reproducing everything NxM times.  2) Use a phonetic spelling scheme similar to Soundex.  3) Use a more general algorithm that essentially calculates the similarity between words.